# initialize matrices in tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have 6 matrices, which my model will learn,  I defined them as follow:

```
self.R= tf.get_variable('R_',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[6,300 ,300],
           initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(maxval=0.1, minval=-0.1))
```

what I need to do is to change the initialization. I want to initialize each one of them as an identity matrix. 
can someone help me with that?

Comment: You want to simply create 6 300x300 identity matrixes?

Comment: yes, instead of initializing them as a random I want to initialize them as an identity matrix, inside the get_variable not as a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a 6x300x300 matrix where each 300x300 array is an identity matrix you can simply:

```
import numpy as np;

dimension = 300 
singleIdentityMatrix = np.identity(dimension, dtype= np.float32) 
stackedMatrix = np.dstack( [singleIdentityMatrix] * 6)
```

and pass this matrix with

```
self.R = tf.Variable(initial_value = stackedMatrix)
```

Comment: I pass this matrix to the initializer ?

Comment: try self.R = stackedMatrix

Comment: unfortunately, by doing = or tf.assign the R transformed to a constant

Comment: tf.assign(R,np.transpose(stackedMatrix))
the matrices became an I identity matrix but the optimizer deal with it as a constant

Comment: @Abrar I saw you accepted my answer. Maybe you could upvote also.

Answer (score 1):

[identity initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/initializers/identity) should help, it's available in TensorFlow 1.3. this interface only support 2D array.

Change your code into

`self.R= tf.get_variable('R_',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[6,300 ,300],
           initializer=tf.initializers.identity())`

Another way is you generate a identity matrix with numpy and as initial value of Variable, but the identity matrix size can not too large, which will cause 'tf.Graph' larger than 2GB

Comment: my version 1.2.1 and it gives me the error: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'initializers'

Comment: In 1.2 the code is under contrib module  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/keras/initializers/Identity